# Java: Check if JButton is Pressed inside Frame MousePressListener

Tags: java

I have JFrame that has a button inside it. When the user click anywhere on the frame, I want to check if the button was pressed or clicked before it.

For example if the user the click on the frame without clicking the button first it should say "button not pressed" but if the user click the button then press anywhere on the frame then it should say "button is pressed".

My Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final int FRAME_WIDTH  = 400;
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle("Test 1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final JButton btnRectangle = new JButton("Rectangle");
        panel.add(btnRectangle);

        class MousePressListener implements MouseListener
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
            {
                int x = event.getX() ; 
                int y = event.getY() ;

                System.out.println("you have press the mouse at X : " + x + " and Y : " + y);

                if(btnRectangle.getModel().isSelected())
                    System.out.println("the button is pressed");
                else 
                    System.out.println("the button is NOT pressed");
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){}
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){}
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){}
        }

        MousePressListener mListener = new MousePressListener();
        frame.addMouseListener(mListener);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

As you can see I tried to check if the button was clicked inside the JFrame MousePressed Listener. But with no success. I also look at the question:

[How can I check that JButton is pressed? If the isEnable() is not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799131/how-can-i-check-that-jbutton-is-pressed-if-the-isenable-is-not-work)

But Can't seem to get anywhere, please help

Comment: I recommend adding an `ActionListener` to the `JButton`, that should take priority over frame-level listeners. That way you have your custom `JFrame` `MouseListener` and a separate listener that handles `JButton` logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done do following steps,

```
public class Test2 
{
    static boolean isPressed = false;

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        .....
             btnRectangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                isPressed = true;
            }
        });
        .....


        class MousePressListener implements MouseListener
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
            {
                if(!isPressed){
                     System.out.println("the button is NOT pressed");

                }else{
                    System.out.println("the button is pressed");
                }
               .....
             }
          }


     }

}
```

See output,

[image]