# unable to check if button is pressed

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to check if a jbutton is pressed, but idk how to do it. This is how i am trying it right now.

```
private void checker() {
int first=0;
int second=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.size(); i++) {
        if(buttonList.get(i).getModel().isPressed()){
            first++;
        }
        if(buttonList.get(i).getModel().isPressed()){
            second++;
        }

    }
    if((first==2)||(second==2)){
      for(int i=0;i<buttonList.size();i++){
          if(buttonList.get(i).getModel().isPressed()){

          }else{
              buttonList.get(i).setEnabled(false);
          }
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check that JButton is pressed? If the isEnable() is not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799131/how-can-i-check-that-jbutton-is-pressed-if-the-isenable-is-not-work)

Comment: A `JButton` wil only be pressed for a moment. `JCheckBox`, `JRadioButton` and `JToggleButton` will toggle between "pressed" and "unpressed" states each time they are actioned. Perhaps you're using the wrong type of button?  If you want to know when the button is triggered, then you should be using a `ActionListener`

Comment: Next time check if your question has not already been asked.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799131/how-can-i-check-that-jbutton-is-pressed-if-the-isenable-is-not-work